# 501 Error when requesting large video

Tags: html, iis, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to view a video over my LAN by streaming it over my IIS 5.1 server.

The video is 4 GB big, not sure if it is too big.
When I go to the URL at which the video is located I get the error 501:
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Supported

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at following described in the [Microsoft website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-help-website-http-errors#1TC=windows-81):

> The website is unable to display the webpage (HTTP 501 or 505)
>
> Error 501 (HTTP 501 - Not Implemented) means that the website you're
>   visiting isn't set up to display the content your browser is
>   requesting. For example, the browser is asking for a file with a video
>   extension (.AVI), but is telling the website it's looking for an HTML
>   page. Error 505 (HTTP 505 - Version Not Supported) means the website
>   doesn't support the version of the HTTP protocol your browser uses to
>   request the webpage (HTTP/1.1 being the most common).

Comment: I there any way to allow the .m4v file on iis?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Try another browser to see whether the error is exist yet or not.
For IE browser, follow these steps: [Error 501/505](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811262)